# Why does the harddrive pause causing the system to freeze for under 60 seconds when launching an application?

Tags: hard-drive

Why does that occur? The laptop is running Windows 7 and has had new memory sticks installed. I also ran a check on the harddrive and there were no known issues.

Comment: Probably should check to see if your harddrive is really acting up.  Go under Control Panel/System/Performance Tools/ Advanced.  Then run a System health report. . .

Comment: @surfasb - What am I looking for?

Comment: When you run the health report, you'll see it.  It prints nice yellow and red icons.  If they don't show up, we can eliminate driver troubles.

Comment: @surfasb - It displays a screen with green icons bar one noting it cannot identify the antivirus installed. The antivirus installed is AVAST.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Start -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> and you want to look at Windows Logs -> System.  If your disk is causing trouble, you'll see a bunch of events named "disk" and saying that there are errors in reading or writing.  A failing hard drive can cause what you are experiencing, but there are also many other causes.

Other things that could cause this off the top of my head are antivirus programs that are trying to verify executables with an online service but can't reach the service for some reason, and network drives that aren't reachable.

Comment: There is no event entry of 'disk'. The only time this seems to occur is when I am either launching an application such as VMWare or when copying multiple small files which amount to large files from one drive to another i.e. when the drive is reading and writing multiple times. When it does this, not only does the harddrive pause but also all other services e.g. wireless